# Is the set $E$ is open, closed, compact in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> **Question**: regard $\mathbb{Q}$ as a metric space with $d(p,q)=|p-q|$.
>   Let $E$ be the set of all $p\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $2<p^2<3$. Show
>   that $E$ is closed and bounded, but $E$ is not compact. Also show that
>   $E$ is open.

**My attempt**: given set $E$ is,

$$E=\{p\in \mathbb{Q} : 2<p^2<3\}$$

Clearly, $E=(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)\cap \mathbb{Q}$ where $(\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3)$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}$. Hence $E$ is open in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Similarly $E$ is closed because $E=[\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3]\cap \mathbb{Q}$.

$E$ is bounded is obvious.

**I don't know** ** how to show $E$ is not compact in $\mathbb{Q}$ **. I know I have to find an open cover of $E$ which do not have finite subcover. But, is there is any other easy way to show $E$ is not compact in $\mathbb{Q}$?

**Further**, is my solution for showing $E$ is open, closed in $\mathbb{Q}$ is correct?

Please help.

Comment: Beware! $E = \big(]\sqrt{2}; \sqrt{3}[  \cup  ] -\sqrt{3}; -\sqrt{2}[ \big) \cap \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @OlivierRoche sir, thank you so much for notifying. I didn't notice the negative part of $E$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Proof of non compacity using [sequential compactness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space)**

Consider the sequence defined by induction: $u_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\left(u_n+\frac{2}{u_n}\right)$ with $u_1=\frac{3}{2}$.

It is a sequence of rational numbers, decreasing and converging to $\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbb R$. Hence $u_n \in E$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

$E$ is sequentially compact space as it is a metric space. As $(u_n)$ is a bounded sequence, it would have a converging subsequence if $E$ was compact. But that can't be as the limit is unique. So the limit would be $\sqrt{2}$ which doesn't belong to $E$.

Regarding your proof for openness, you missed the fact that $E$ has a *negative* part. So you should say
$$E=((-\sqrt 3, -\sqrt 2) \cap \mathbb Q) \cup ((\sqrt 2, \sqrt 3) \cap \mathbb Q).$$ And the union of open subspaces is open. Same for closeness as a finite union of closed subspaces is closed.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for the beautiful answer. Sir as you replied to @ Oplossing answer, is there is negative part of $E$? If yes then is my attempt to show openess and closedness is correct?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi Good point! I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Sir, can I used the fact that compactness is topological property! Hence $E$ will be compact in $\mathbb{Q}$ iff it is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ and clearly by Heine borel theorem $E$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$ as it is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Am I correct sir?

Answer (score 3):

Consider the open cover $\mathcal U = \{(a,b) \subseteq \mathbf Q : \sqrt 2 < a < b<\sqrt 3\}$ of $E$. Suppose that $\mathcal U'$ is a finite sub cover of $\mathcal U$. There is some interval $(a,b)\in \mathcal U'$, such that for any other interval $(a',b') \in \mathcal U$: $a\leq a'$. Now note that there is a rational $u$ between $\sqrt  2$ and $a$. Then $u\in E$, but there is no interval in $\mathcal U'$ that contains $u$. A contradiction, hence $E$ is not compact.

Comment: You need to take $\mathcal U = \{(a,b) \subseteq \mathbf Q : \sqrt 2 < a < b<\sqrt 3\} \cup \{(a,b) \subseteq \mathbf Q : -\sqrt 3 < a < b<-\sqrt 2\}$ to get a cover of $E$. The one of your answer doesn't cover the "negative" part of $E$.

Answer (score 1):

*Mistake: You have $E= \{\sqrt 2\,,\,\sqrt 3)\cap \Bbb Q$ which is wrong. $$E=\{p\in \Bbb Q: 2<p^2<3\}=[\,(-\sqrt 3\,,\,-\sqrt 2) \cup (\sqrt 2\,,\,\sqrt 3)\,]\cap \Bbb Q.$$

**If $T$ is a topology on a set $X$ and $Y\subset X$ then the subspace topology $T_Y$ on $Y$ is $T_Y=\{t\cap Y: t\in T\}.$ And if $S\subset Y$ then $Cl_{T_Y}(S),$ the closure of $S$ in the space $Y,$ is $Y\cap Cl_T(S),$ where $Cl_T(S)$ is the closure of $Y$ in the space $X.$ In particular, $S$ is closed in $Y$ iff $S=Y\cap Cl_T(S).$

An important property, if  $T$ is generated by a metric $d$ on $X,$ is that  $T_Y$ co-incides with the topology on $Y$ generated by "the restriction of $d$ to $Y$". Applying this with $X=\Bbb R$ and $d(x,y)=|x-y|$ for all $x,y \in \Bbb R,$ and with $Y=\Bbb Q$ and $S=E,$ we have at once that $E$ is open and closed in $\Bbb Q,$ just as you said.

*** Let $$C=\{(-(\infty,\sqrt 2)\cap E\} \cup D$$ where $D= \{(y,\infty)\cap E:\sqrt 2\,<y\in \Bbb R\}.$

Now $C$ is an open cover of $E$ in the space $\Bbb Q.$

If $F\subset C$ then clearly $F$ is not a cover of $E$ if $F\cap D\ne \emptyset.$

But if $F$ is a $finite$ subset of $C$ and $F\cap D\ne \emptyset$ then there exists $y_0=\min \{y:(y,\infty)\cap E\in F\}$ and we have $\sqrt 2\,<y_0,$ so $\cup F$ is disjoint from the non-empty set $(\sqrt 2\,,y_0)\cap \Bbb Q =(\sqrt 2\,,y_0)\cap E,$ so $F$ is not a cover of $E$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Trying to understand the last part "if $F$ is finite subset of $C$ ....." Sir can you please elaborate. What it means $\cup F$ ? and how it is disjoint from the mentioned non-empty set. Sir if it's disjoint then why $F$ is not a cover of $E$? Is it because of $F\cap D≠ ∅$. Sir please help.

Comment: Definition: $\cup F=\cup_{(f\in F)}\, f.$ Sometimes written with \bigcup as $\bigcup F$....Definition. $F$ is a cover of $E$ iff $\cup F\supset E$.....If $y_0$ exists then for any $(y,\infty)\cap E\in F$ we have $y_0\le y$ so $(y,\infty)\cap E\subset (y_0,\infty)\cap E,$ and therefore $\cup F\subset [\, (-\infty, \sqrt 2)\cap E\,]\cup [\,(y_0,\infty)\cap E\,].$

Comment: continued from previous comment:... so points in $(\sqrt 2,\,y_0)\cap E$ do not belong to $\cup F$ so $\neg (\cup F\supset E).$

Comment: Sir, why you removed the word "unless"? (In your answer). I think $F$ is finite subset of $C$ then $F$ is not cover of $E$ if $F\cap D=\emptyset$

Comment: Further, Sir, can I used the fact that compactness is topological property! Hence $E$ will be compact in $\mathbb{Q}$ iff it is compact in $\mathbb{R}$ and clearly by Heine borel theorem $E$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$ as it is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Am I correct sir?

Comment: Re: Your last comment: YES. $\Bbb Q$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$ so the topology on $E$ as a subspace of $\Bbb Q$  is the same as the topology on $E$ as a subspace of $\Bbb R$. And a compact subspace of $\Bbb R$ must be a closed sub$set$ of $\Bbb R$ (because $\Bbb R$ is a Hausdorff space).

Comment: Re: Your 2nd last comment: If $F$ is a finite subset of $C$ then  if $F\cap D$ is empty then $F$ is not a cover of $E$ because NO subset of $C$ that has empty intersection with $D$ can be a cover of $E$. So we go on, to consider finite $F\subset C$ such that $F\cap D\ne \phi$..... (Some people object to using \phi  (i.e. $\phi$) for \emptyset but I have heard professionals in person using it verbally.)